# Не могу перевести py файл с модулем multiprocessing в exe

Tags: python, многопоточность

У меня есть программа, которая парсит сайты через `Selenium webdriver` и `bs4`. Также, я использую `multiprocessing Pool` (5-10 процессов). Py файл функционирует как надо, но при переводе в exe файл при запуске открывается консоль и ничего не происходит. В диспетчере задать создается около 100 процессов этой программы (хотя в `Pool` указываю 8).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from multiprocessing import Pool

def close_driver(driver):
    driver.close()

def get_match_links(date):
    link = "https://hawkbets.com/matches/recent?date="

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    driver.get(link + date)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="wrap"]')))
        source = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
        elements = soup.find_all('a', class_='wrap') 
    except Exception:
        print('Не удался парсинг страницы с матчами- ', link + date)
        return None

    match_list = []
    for element in elements:
        match = {
            'link': 'https://hawkbets.com' + element.get('href'),
            'date': date,
            'team1': "",
            'team2': "",
            'team1_pick': [],
            'team2_pick': [],
            'result': ""
        }
        match_list.append(match)

    close_driver(driver)
    print('УДАЧНЫЙ парсинг страницы с матчами- ', link + date)

    return match_list

def get_match_info(match):
    match_link = match['link']
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    driver.get(match_link)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="team"]//div[@class="name"]')))
    except Exception:
        print('Парсинг страницы не удался ', match_link)

    source = driver.page_source

    close_driver(driver)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

    match['team1'] = soup.find_all('div', class_="team")[0].find('div', class_="name").text
    match['team2'] = soup.find_all('div', class_="team")[1].find('div', class_="name").text

    team1_pick_elements = soup.find('div', class_="picks").find_all('div', class_="team")[0].find_all('div', class_="pick")
    for element in team1_pick_elements:
        match['team1_pick'].append(element.find('img', class_="hero_image").get('title'))

    team2_pick_elements = soup.find('div', class_="picks").find_all('div', class_="team")[1].find_all('div', class_="pick")
    for element in team2_pick_elements:
        match['team2_pick'].append(element.find('img', class_="hero_image").get('title'))
    print('УДАЧНЫЙ парсинг матча - ', match_link)

    with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(match))
        f.write('\n')
        print('Успешная запись в файл!')

    return match

def make_all(date):
    match_list = get_match_links(date)

    for match in match_list[:-1]:
        get_match_info(match)


def make_date_list():

    try:
        year1 = open('date.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')[0].split('-')[0]
        month1 = open('date.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')[0].split('-')[1]
        day1 = open('date.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')[0].split('-')[2]

        year2 = open('date.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')[1].split('-')[0]
        month2 = open('date.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')[1].split('-')[1]
        day2 = open('date.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')[1].split('-')[2]

        start_date = datetime.date(int(year1), int(month1), int(day1)) 
        end_date = datetime.date(int(year2), int(month2), int(day2)) 
        date_list_old = [start_date + datetime.timedelta(n) for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days))] 
        date_list = []
        for date in date_list_old:
            date_ = str(date)
            date_list.append(date_)
            print('Список дат создан!')

    except ValueError:
        print('1.0', 'Ошибка: Неверный формат даты\n')
        return None

    return date_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(int(open('procs.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')[0]))
    pool.map(make_all, open('date.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')[:-1])
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо :)

Comment: Я оформил ответом. Если помогло, можете отметить ответ как принятый (поставить галку слева от ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Под Windows для поддержки модулем `multiprocessing` упаковки кода в exe нужно добавить вызов функции `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` в блок `if __name__ == "__main__":`.

Пример кода из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support

def f():
    print('hello world!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    Process(target=f).start()
```